Interleave chain of inequalities with explanations
I have a very long chain of inequalities:
    \begin{align*}
    d_{DTW}(w'_\epsilon,v) 
    &\leq \sum_{(i',j') \in P'} c(h_{\constantsAndvInfiniteEpsilons}(w_{i'}),v_{j'}) + \sum_{(i',j') \in P''} c(w_{i'},v_{j'})\\
    &\leq \sum_{(i',j') \in P} c(h_{\constantsAndvInfiniteEpsilons}(w_{i'}),w_{i'}) + \sum_{(i',j') \in P'} c(w_{i'},v_{j'}) + \sum_{(i',j') \in P''} c(w_{i'},v_{j'})\\
    &\leq \sum_{(i',j') \in P} c(h_{\constantsAndvInfiniteEpsilons}(w_{i'}),w_{i'}) + \sum_{(i',j') \in P} c(w_{i'},v_{j'})\\
    &\leq \sum_{(i',j') \in P} c(h_{\constantsAndvInfiniteEpsilons}(w_{i'}),w_{i'}) + d_{DTW}(w_\epsilon,v)\\
    &\leq \epsilon * \sum_{(i',j') \in P} c(h(\kappa_{i'}),\kappa_{i'}) + d_{DTW}(w_\epsilon,v)\\
    &\leq \delta' * \sum_{(i',j') \in P} c(h(\kappa_{i'}),\kappa_{i'}) + d_{DTW}(w_\epsilon,v)\\
    &\leq \frac{b-b'}{\sum_{(i',j') \in P} c(h(\kappa_{i'}),\kappa_{i'})} * \sum_{(i',j') \in P} c(h(\kappa_{i'}),\kappa_{i'}) + d_{DTW}(w_\epsilon,v)\\
    &\leq b-b' + d_{DTW}(w_\epsilon,v)\\
    &\leq b
\end{align*}

I was hoping to get this interleaved with explanations for each step of the inequality.
Which method can I combine with align to make this happen?

Insert \noalign{explaining text} after each \\.

The amsmath package, which also provides the align* environment, provides a macro called \intertext which does the job you're looking to accomplish. The mathtools package, which is a superset of the amsmath package, provides a macro called \shortintertext that's especially suitable for, well, short interleaved explanations. The following screenshot illustrates the outputs of both \intertext and \shortintertext.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,lipsum}
\providecommand{\constantsAndvInfiniteEpsilons}{ZZZ} % ?

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    d_{\mathrm{DTW}}(w'_\epsilon,v) 
    &\leq \smashoperator{\sum_{(i',j') \in P'}}  
      c(h_{\constantsAndvInfiniteEpsilons}(w_{i'}),v_{j'}) 
      + \smashoperator{\sum_{(i',j') \in P''}} c(w_{i'},v_{j'})\\
    \intertext{\lipsum[1][1-3]}
    &\leq \smashoperator{\sum_{(i',j') \in P}} 
      c(h_{\constantsAndvInfiniteEpsilons}(w_{i'}),w_{i'}) 
      + \smashoperator{\sum_{(i',j') \in P'}} c(w_{i'},v_{j'}) 
      + \smashoperator{\sum_{(i',j') \in P''}} c(w_{i'},v_{j'})\\
    \intertext{\lipsum[1][1-3]}
    &\leq \smashoperator{\sum_{(i',j') \in P}} 
      c(h_{\constantsAndvInfiniteEpsilons}(w_{i'}),w_{i'}) 
      + \smashoperator{\sum_{(i',j') \in P}} c(w_{i'},v_{j'})\\
    \intertext{\lipsum[1][1-3]}
    &\leq \smashoperator{\sum_{(i',j') \in P}} 
      c(h_{\constantsAndvInfiniteEpsilons}(w_{i'}),w_{i'}) 
      + d_{\mathrm{DTW}}(w_\epsilon,v)\\
    \intertext{\lipsum[1][1-3]}
    &\leq \epsilon * \smashoperator{\sum_{(i',j') \in P}} 
      c(h(\kappa_{i'}),\kappa_{i'}) 
      + d_{\mathrm{DTW}}(w_\epsilon,v)\\
    \shortintertext{\lipsum[1][1]}
    &\leq \delta' * \smashoperator{\sum_{(i',j') \in P}} 
      c(h(\kappa_{i'}),\kappa_{i'}) 
      + d_{\mathrm{DTW}}(w_\epsilon,v)\\
    \shortintertext{\lipsum[1][1]}
    &\leq \frac{b-b'}{\sum_{(i',j') \in P}
      c(h(\kappa_{i'}),\kappa_{i'})} * 
      \smashoperator{\sum_{(i',j') \in P}} 
      c(h(\kappa_{i'}),\kappa_{i'}) 
      + d_{\mathrm{DTW}}(w_\epsilon,v)\\
    \shortintertext{\lipsum[1][1]}
    &\leq b-b' + d_{\mathrm{DTW}}(w_\epsilon,v)\\
    \shortintertext{\lipsum[1][1]}
    &\leq b\,.
\end{align*}
\end{document} 

